# How to get and insert values at span tag of model through params in a edit nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models as following:

Order Model

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_lines
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_lines, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['quantity'].blank?}
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_lines
end
```

OrderLine Model

```
class OrderLine < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, optional: true
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Order edit.html.erb view

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :order_lines  do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'order_lines/form_sub', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

OrderLines order_lines/_form.html.erb view

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>***I want to put the name of the product here orderLine.product.name***</li>
    <li>Quantity: <%= f.number_field :quantity></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As indicated above, I want to get the product.name of the current orderLine produced through field_for loop. 
I have tried f.object, but it is very weird to work it. 
When I do the following:

```
<%= debug f.object.product %>
```

Shows following output

```
--- !ruby/object:Product
raw_attributes:
  id: 7
  name: Dell Computers
  ....
```

But when I try to use the following in the view code

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>f.object.product.name </li>
    <li>Quantity: <%= f.number_field :quantity></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I get error

```
NoMethodError
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

What can I do? I have been stuck here for 2 days!

Comment: Is `has_many :orderLines` a typo in `Product`?

Comment: @31piy sorry i made the typo when I tried to copy the code into stackoverflow.

Comment: Something is accessing `title` of `nil`. Can you search `title` in your project?

Comment: once again that was a typo. sorry, @31piy. I simplified the original complicated code into the rudimentary code. I think there are no more typos.

Comment: Clearly, one of the items in `order_lines` has `product` assigned as `nil`. Please check it using `<%= debug f.object.product %>`.